# is it possible to write dictionary in dict format to python file

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I tried to write dictionary to csv file and was successful. But when I read the data and checked its type it was str.

```
import csv
import json
person = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "Fench"]}'
person_dict = json.loads(person)
with open("files/person_.csv", 'a') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Filename", "Extracted","Values"])
    spamwriter.writerow(['xxxx',person_dict])
```

`type(check["Extracted"][0])`

I got as `str`. Is it possible to write without changing to str in csv file ?

Comment: What is `check`?

Comment: check=pd.read_csv("files/person_.csv")

Answer (score 0):

No but you could convert it back to a dict as in the beginning of your code

```
your_dict = json.load(json_data)
```